# Google Apps Custom Function - For loop fails to progress

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

***FOR LOOP CAUSING ISSUES:***

```
  for (row = calendar_array.length - 1; row >= 0; row--)
  {
    for (column = calendar_array[0].length - 1; column >= 1; column--)
    {
       //if (calendar_array[row][column] == alternative_activities[row2][1] && calendar_array[row][0] == calendar_array[arrayRowPosition][0])
      if (check_array.indexOf(calendar_array[row][column]) > -1 && calendar_array[row][0] == calendar_array[arrayRowPosition][0])
      {
        var hold = check_array.indexOf(calendar_array[row][column]);
        return alternative_activities[hold+1][1] + '\n Found in [' + row + '][' + column + ']';
      }
    }
  }
```

I've stepped through the function confirming that the arrays return the desired data into the function, whether from the Calendar table or the Alternate Workout table. The issue appears to be the loop pasted above.

**Source Data:**

- Rows before current location in 'Calendar' table
- 'Alternate Workouts' table on the [same sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16li86UxKwDl4LUzgEdpfWdbZuDYcZ0t-adNJN56-bzQ/edit?pli=1#gid=0).
- Both sets of data pulled into the function are on the [same
  spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16li86UxKwDl4LUzgEdpfWdbZuDYcZ0t-adNJN56-bzQ/edit?pli=1#gid=0) to make it easier to refer to the various sets of data.

**Goal**:

1. Look for the **matching workout** in the the elements in the *same row* or *above* the CURRENT location in the calendar from the '*Alternate Workouts' table* (using indexOf)
2. The **TYPE** (Column B - Rows 3 to 18) in the 'Calendar' table MUST ALSO match the **TYPE** of workout from the *'Alternate Workouts' table* (Column A - Rows 25 to 46)
3. **Desired Result** - Find the value that matches point 1 & 2 from the 'Alternate Workout' table and get the *NEXT* workout.

**The results should** follow the order of the workouts from the *'Alternate Workouts' table* to follow a schedule as designed in the calendar.

The **IDEAL** result is in the image below.
N.B. *ONLY the white cells are the ones with the formula.*

Examples:

1. 'Pilates' is followed by 'Elevate' as they do in the *Alternate
   Workouts table* since both ALSO share 'Cycling' as the TYPE of
   workout.
   2 - 'Poker' is followed by 'Sudoku' as they do in the
   *Alternate Workouts table* since both ALSO share 'Boxing' as the TYPE of workout

[image]

**ACTUAL RESULT:**
I included a loop count to illustrate the manner that the for loop continues to refer to the same element and fails to advance past the first returned values, as shown in the image below:

[image]

I'm fairly sure that I'm missing something but after a couple of days of staring at the same issue, I'm hoping someone might provide insight as to the issue. Thanks

Comment: Please simply your [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. I'll go ahead and close this. The problem only occurred within a spreadsheet

Comment: The chances of pretty good that if you work on creating  a simplified example you will solve the problem on your own.  At least that's been my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to create the same programming logic in an simplified format but found a work around.